# Bash break statement doesn't exit loop

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a code that looks like this:

```
while [ true ] ; do
case "$curr_token" in
(";") break 
    ;;
(")") break 
    ;;
(",") break 
    ;;
esac
    parse_term
    next_token
if [ "$curr_type" != "<symbol>" ] ; then
    echo "Not an operator"
    exit
fi
echo "$token" >> ${file}P.xml
next_token
done
```

Here parse_term and next_token are subroutines inside my code. If the variable `$curr_token` is among the cases listed (i.e. among `;`, `)`, `'`) break statement will be executed. But even if `$curr_token` above is among the cases listed the statements following the case block are executed.

Please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Works for me, although I didn't know you could put an initial `(` in the cases. You might have quoting problems elsewhere.

Comment: What is the value of $cur_token? Are you *sure* it is what you think it is?

Comment: Are you sure `$cur_token` is among the cases? Simply first print `echo $curr_token` and verify it.I see nothing wrong, it should work.

Comment: `while [ true ]` doesn't do what you think it does. The correct syntax is simply `while true`; or, more generally, `while cmd` executes the loop as long as `cmd` returns a zero (aka success, aka true) exit code.

Comment: You could simplify to `case $curr_token in ([);,]) break;; esac`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter 2 to the break sentence:

[The break command may optionally take a parameter. A plain break terminates only the innermost loop in which it is embedded, but a break N breaks out of N levels of loop.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loopcontrol.html#EX28)

Comment: That's not the problem here; there is only one level of loop.